# JS: cannot assign to a nested array using nested for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I got a "TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" from this code snipet. Can anyone help me with this! Thank you very much

```
let array = [[]];
function generateField(width, height) {
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        };
    };
    console.log(array);
    return array;
}

generateField(5, 5);
```

Comment: you have 2 arrays, You're attempting to write to more than two arrays. You'll need to construct additional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the array declaration be : `let array = [][]` instead of `let array = [[]]` ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize the array before trying to insert to the sencond level.

```js
let array = [];
function generateField(width, height) {
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        if(!array[i]) array[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        };
    };
    console.log(array);
    return array;
}

generateField(5, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Please consider these tips

- Do not use `array` as a variable name because it could produce error in some browsers
- Because Javascript `Array` is basically linked list there is no need to declare `Array` in this way `let array = [[]]`. For sure more suitable is creating new `Array` and push it to existing `Array`
- Maybe declare `let array = [[]]` inside `generateField` function to make it more reusable because looking at your code I see you want function which creates new `Array` with `n` rows and `m` columns with random numbers and when `let array = [[]]` is outside your function will be modified every time when you call `generateField`

#### Working code below:

```js
function generateField(width, height) {
    let rows = []
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        let columns = []
        for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            columns.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3))
        }
        rows.push(columns)
    };
    return [...rows] // create a copy of `Array` named `rows`
}

let matrix = generateField(3, 4)
console.log(matrix)
```

**Output**

```sh
Array(4) [ (3) […], (3) […], (3) […], (3) […] ]
​
0: Array(3) [ 0, 1, 2 ]
​
1: Array(3) [ 0, 2, 0 ]
​
2: Array(3) [ 1, 2, 2 ]
​
3: Array(3) [ 2, 1, 2 ]
​
length: 4
​
<prototype>: Array []
```